# Show floating button or menu on gridview item click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, popupmenu, android-contextmenu

I have a gridview like this:

[image]

Now, when I click on the button's pencil icon,in the gridview item, I want to show  three buttons. Maybe like Floating button.

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/pencil"
        android:background="@color/listrow"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/pencil"
        android:background="@color/listrow"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My code to show button Gone at positison item grid:

```
pen = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        pen1 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        pen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pen1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "At: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Anyone can give any ideal?

Comment: You can play with Visible,Invisible adn Gone fucntionality of the View

Comment: I did that, but it get error, when I click at pencil of HungNN1 the pencil of the last item in grid show Visible, not at pencil of HungNN1.

Comment: ...Than show yours code...we will check it that , where is you going to be wrong

Comment: ok. My code on the question.

Comment: Can u give any ideal?

Comment: ...hmm...I still watting

Answer (score 1):

It is better to implement Popup Menu when click on the pencil image. By using Popup menu we can add multiple buttons and actions for each menu item.
To implement popupmenu check this url ::http://javatechig.com/android/android-popup-menu-example

Comment: Can popup menu show like button. I understand that it only show context menu. Is that right?

Comment: Not exact buttons, it only shows you menu item view

Comment: But I want it show like button, can u give me any ideal?

Answer (score 0):

What if you add some buttons and set the Visibility to `Visibility.GONE`

Comment: I did that, but it get error, when I click at pencil of HungNN1 the pencil of the last item in grid show Visible, not at pencil of HungNN1

Answer (score 0):

You can create ContextMenu for your gridview items.

First, in your activity's `onCreate()`, register your gridview for contextMenu :

```
registerForContextMenu(myGridview);
```

Now, you should override two methods `onCreateContextMenu()` and `onContextItemSelected()`

```
@Override   
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)  
{  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");    
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "action one");//groupId, itemId, order, title   
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "action two");   
} 

.
.
.

@Override    
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){    
        if(item.getTitle().equals("action one"){  
             //your code
        }    
        else if(item.getTitle().equals("action two"){  
           //your code
        }else{  
           return false;  
        }    
      return true;    
  }    
}
```

Android context menu appears when user press long click on the element. It is also known as floating menu.

Comment: I can do that. But I want do like my question. I want click button than long press. Can u give any ideal?

Answer (score 0):

in that adapter class add implements OnMenuItemClickListener.

```
class Abc extends BaseAdapater implements OnMenuItemClickListener{

//override all implement menthods of BaseAdaptar and OnMenuItemClickListener

// now in method add popupmenu on item
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_layout, parent, false);//Inflate layout

        TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.productname);
name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(ctx, finalView);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(Abc.this);
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.product_menu);
 popupMenu.show();
            }
        });

// override menu click event code as your menu items
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
return false;
}
}
```

If you have any doubt comment me.